# saving data to the database

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

im trying to save data to the database but im getting an error **Creating default object from empty value**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; use App\Message;

class MessageController extends Controller 
{ 
    public function submit(Request $request)
    { 
        $this->validate($request, [ 'name' => 'required', 'email' => 'required']);

        //create a new message
        $messge= new Message;

        $message->name=$request->name;
        $message->email = $request->email;
        $message->message = $request->message;

        //message save

        $message -> save();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: $messge= new Message; ???
$messge= new Message();

Comment: thanks i put it but still its not working

Comment: Talg123, that is not a syntax error as php accepts it.

Comment: Your issue is following: You set a variable called $messge. Then you are going to set the members(name, email, message) from a variable called $message. Fix your typo and it should work ;)

Comment: so im still new with laravel i hadbeen following a tutorial and now im stuck on this last code please help

Comment: thanks it worked but there is a new error                                                                                    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'message' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `messages` (`name`, `email`, `message`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hhhhhh, hhhhhhhhhh, , 2019-07-12 09:14:11, 2019-07-12 09:14:11))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat you are experiencing is "typo". You are initializing the model with variable `$messge` and then you are accessing it using a different name `$message`. Correct code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

use App\Message;

class MessageController extends Controller 
{ 
    public function submit(Request $request)
    { 
        $this->validate(
            $request, 
            [ 
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required'
            ]
        );

        //create a new message
        $message= new Message;

        $message->name=$request->name;
        $message->email = $request->email;
        $message->message = $request->message;

        //message save
        $message->save();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```